# encoding conversion in iphone application

Tags: iphone, encoding

how can i covert convert my current encoding NSUTF8StringEncoding into kCFStringEncodingDOSChineseTrad. Please help me out

Comment: Please let us know which objects you're using (NSData, NSString, etc) in order to get a more helpful answer. NSString has methods that will allow this, depending on what you're trying to do

Comment: i am fetching data from the database & want to convert it into chinese. I am using NSMutabledata for response & than converting it into string for feeding into NSDictionary I am using JSON for web services

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding` can help you, I don't test it:

```
NSStringEncoding enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding (kCFStringEncodingDOSChineseTrad);
```

Comment: it's not working please suggest me something i am stuck in that i am really thankful to you

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no more ideas :-(